# How to respond to "Drive API requires updates to your code before Sep 13, 2021"?

Tags: google-drive-api

Today I received an email titled "Drive API requires updates to your code before Sep 13, 2021".

[image]

As above `#1` says the `requests to the Drive API` need to add the specific header, however, I don't know exactly what kind of requests need to add the header, the link `#2` [the Drive API guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys) doesn't clarify this either.

Does anyone know what exact requests will be affected and need to change?

Comment: Did it ask you to click on a link? DO NOT. Instead, hover your cursor over it to see where it leads. This sounds like spam to me. Btw, your question is badly off topic here. Please read the help section, and [ask].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica it is not spam Google is "update will change the links used for some files" and if OP reads the email they will know what is effected.   Only they can decide what in their code will need to be changed.  This is not something we can help them with.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear you point out that this is off topic.

In the body of the email, there was the following statement and a link to the following URL

"To get help with these changes, see the Drive API support options on [our website](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support)."


Should I close this topic?

Comment: What else does the email say? Why not copy it here? Is it the same as this blog post? https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/06/drive-file-link-updates.html

Comment: Same here, the email is legit. However, I made a few queries to file metadata endpoints, trying to create the described use case and obtain a resource key in the metadata, but so far no luck. If someone could provide step-by-step instructions for that, I would be grateful. The email basically contains the same information as [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys), which in my opinion could be more clear.

Comment: @Zoyd - You need to update Google.Apis.Drive.v3 package to the latest version and you can see the `resouceKey` field/property, but from my test, it always returns null, maybe will have value till Sep 13?

Answer (score 0):

I also get this such E-Mail, I have a project that use API Drive to store my file in Google Drive,
I hope find such tutorial to update my code in order to follow this instruction from google.

In my opinion, Google just give resourceKey to access shared file to public, in order to the url more secure.

and how to get resourceKey return from google drive when my file upload succesfully from my project with Api Drive, and how to implement it.

Thanks for everyone who give us more explanation about it.

Comment: You need to update Google.Apis.Drive.v3 package to the latest version, then when you query files, there is a `ResourceKey` field on the file object as mentioned in google's email or [the link here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys).

But I am confused as you, don't know what exactly need to do in our code, Google didn't clearly list what cases/requests need to change, the doc above only says need to add the resourceKey in the header of the request, I don't know what all other kind of requests that need to change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think, we must wait for the clear doc from Google. Do we still can upload to drive via Api in our apps using script like the past?. Only need resource key when that file shared to anyone who have the link. I wait the way how to get the resource key when I upload file from via Api in order to add this key to my database for sharing file to public automatically. Please share me the Guidance if you get it. Thanks bro.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I've decided to contact Google Support through our internal GoogleCloudPlatform administrator.

Finally, I got the message "This question does not meet StackOverflow guidelines" and it was closed, but I will let you know the result if possible.